# Elves asking about a tree slaughter cap in Dwarf Fortress

Tags: dwarf-fortress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens if I ignore the Tree-Hugging Elves?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4300/what-happens-if-i-ignore-the-tree-hugging-elves)

The elves are asking me to cap my tree felling to 100 until the next time they come by.  Currently, I'm unsure as to how much I am felling, so I want to be sure I can control it before I accept.

On the other hand, I'm worried that if I don't accept I might have a fight with them.

Is there a way to ensure that my tree felling falls under 100 and are there any negative sideaffects to accepting the treaty (other than running out of wood)?  What ways can I gather wood other than to fell trees (ie trading, cheating the treaty)?

Also, what are the negative side effects to rejecting or breaking the treaty? Are they the same?

Comment: I swear I've asked this question already. looking... http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4300/what-happens-if-i-ignore-the-tree-huggers

Comment: Ah ok.  I'm going to rename your question so that it contains the word elves in the title.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. The linked question asks what happens - this is asking for a practical solution to pander to their demands.  (Although myself, I'd rather just kill 'em all.)